# How to save a file in assembly language with nasm in Linux x86?

Tags: linux, file, assembly, io, nasm

I'm just wondering how I can throw a buffer to a file. I know I can set up the registers like:

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, (file descriptor here)
mov ecx, myBuffer
mov edx, myBufferLen
int 80h
```

and then close the file with:

```
mov eax, 6
int 80h
```

but I'm not sure how to get the file descriptor. Someone told me that whenever you open a file, after calling the service dispatcher, the eax has the file descriptor. Whatever I try, it doesn't create a new file or save the current one.

Comment: Your `close` call is missing its argument.

Comment: You need to open it first: syscall # is 5 and goes into eax; ebx gets a pointer to the filename (eg, defined in .section .data); ecx gets the permission you open it with (same or'ed bits as in C); and just make edx $0666 for the usual rwx permission.

Comment: After you issue this interrupt, the fd will be in eax.

Comment: You should accept your answer, instead of adding "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov eax, 5 ; __NR_open
mov ebx, filename ; zero terminated!
mov ecx, 2 ; O_WRITE? Check me on this!
mov edx, 777q ; permissions - Check me on this, too!
int 80h
; did we succeed?
cmp eax, -4096
ja exit
mov [descriptor], eax
; and so on...
;...
xor eax, eax ; claim no error
exit:
mov ebx, eax
neg ebx
mov eax, 1 ; __NR_exit
int 80h
```

I'm uncertain on the "magic numbers" for open flags and permissions, and too lazy to look them up right now (fs.h?). You may need to "or" the open flags with O_CREATE to create a new file(?). The trick at "exit:" negates the (negative) ERRNO (if any) so you can read it easily with "echo $?". Something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@gnometorule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315014/gnometorule) for the solution. So this is how you store a buffer into file:
in this case you are receiving the file name as a first parameter when you run the program.

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:

    pop ebx ; this is the amount of parameter received (in this case 2)
    pop ebx ; this is the direction of our program
    pop ebx ; this is the first parameter (our file name eg. "text.txt")
```

so we open it and move it to a buffer to edit or whatever we want with it.

```
textEdit:

    ;we open the file

    mov eax, 5
    push ebx   ; we save the file name in the stack for later use
    mov ecx,0 
    int 80h

    ; and then we move the information read to buffer

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, eax             ; really dont know how this works, but it does.
    mov ecx, fileBuffer
    mov edx, fileBufferSize
    int 80h
```

now fileBuffer (wich is a buffer defined in section .bss) has what we had in the file we opened. Here you can edit the information. When we want to save it back to the file it goes like this:

```
saveFile:

        ;open the file

    mov eax, 5
    pop ebx                ; the file name was stored in the stack, 
    push ebx               ; so we retrieve it and save it back for later use
    mov ecx, 2             ; ecx has the access mode ("2"aloud us to read/write) 
    mov edx, $0666 
    int 80h

        ;now we are going to write to the file

    mov ebx, eax               ; eax has the file descriptor we opened. so we move it to ebx.
    mov eax, 4                 ; we are going to use the write service (#4)
    mov ecx, fileBuffer        ; ecx has the adress of what we want to write
    mov edx, fileBufferSize    ; edx has the amount of bytes we want to write
    int 80h

        ; close the file

    mov eax, 6
    int 80h

    jmp exit  ; jump wherever you want, or end your program... etc.
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, in the las part, when you are going to close th file, ebx needs to have the file descriptor. that would be all.